# Benchmark Testing CPU and GPU

Tags: benchmarks

I would like to benchmark test my CPU and GPU, then compare the results with other people.  I have installed gtkperf and "system profiler and benchmark". These give me some random numbers but I don't know how to compare them with other people.  I've been having issues with graphics performance, so I am particularly keen to get a thorough test done and compare it to other graphics cards. How do I do it?

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/111617/how-to-benchmark-your-linux-system-3-open-source-benchmarking-tools/ check this man

Comment: That's the guide I used already to find the benchmark software. Doesn't help me with my question though.

Comment: Anyone else know anything more on this topic?

Answer (score 0):

I have made a research in order to test my own CPU because i was having some problems with the temperature. I found/used the "cpuburn" to stress/test my CPU. You have some commands related with this program but in my opinion you should use the burnBX for each core.

If u don't have the cpuburn in your PC use this command:

```
apt-get install cpuburn.
```

Answer (score 0):

For a quick cpu-only multi-platform benchmark 7zip is a great tool. You dont have to install an extra program, when your os has no or bad (un)pack functionality.

It supports Linux (Debian, Ubuntu, Fedora, Gentoo and more), FreeBSD, MacOS X, Amiga, Solaris, AIX, DOS and 32 and 64 (AMD64 and IA64) bit Windows.
Source: http://www.7-zip.org/download.html

And of course, it is free software

To start the benchmark: `Extras` => `Benchmark`